# Change retrofit okhttp client at runtime

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

```
fun getClient(token: String, userId: Long, language: String = "en", maxTry: Int = 2): Retrofit {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        okHttpClient.readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        okHttpClient.writeTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        var tryCount = 0
        okHttpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val original = chain.request()
            val request = original.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("secToken", token)
                    .addHeader("userId", userId.toString()).build()
            var response = chain.proceed(request)
            while (!response.isSuccessful && tryCount < maxTry) {
                Log.d("intercept", "Request is not successful - $tryCount")
                tryCount++
                response = chain.proceed(request)
            }
            response
        }

        val builder = GsonBuilder()
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(TransModel::class.java, NotificationTypeAdapter(language))
        val gson = builder.create()

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .build()
        } else {

        }

        //            .client(getHttpClientForFile())
        return retrofit!!
    }
```

Above code is to get singleton retrofit client for every request in App.

What I need to do is what to do in else part of retrofit == null.

Here language is initialized only once. while initializing retrofit, but for second request I don't have idea to change language and maxTry count for request.

**I want to change language, and maxTry at runTime. For every request there must different maxTry count and may language also.**

**Edit:** 
As per suggestion of **@EarlOfEgo** my else part is

```
 retrofit!!.newBuilder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient.build())
                    .build()
```

but It is not changing language.

**Edit 2**: 
*TransModel*

```
class TransModel {

    var en: String = ""
    var gu: String = ""
    var hi: String = ""

    constructor()

    fun get(language: String): String? {
        return when (language) {
            LanguageUtil.languageEn -> {
                en
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageGu -> {
                gu
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageHi -> {
                hi
            }

            else -> {
                null
            }
        }
    }

    constructor(language: String, value: String) {
        when (language) {
            LanguageUtil.languageEn -> {
                en = value
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageGu -> {
                gu = value
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageHi -> {
                hi = value
            }
        }
    }

    fun getValueByLanguage(language: String): String? {
        return when (language) {
            LanguageUtil.languageEn -> {
                en
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageGu -> {
                gu
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageHi -> {
                hi
            }

            else -> {
                null
            }
        }
    }

    fun updateIt(title: TransModel, currentLanguage: String) {
        when (currentLanguage) {
            LanguageUtil.languageEn -> {
                gu = title.gu
                hi = title.hi
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageGu -> {
                en = title.en
                hi = title.hi
            }

            LanguageUtil.languageHi -> {
                gu = title.gu
                en = title.en
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and my *NotificationTypeAdapter*

```
class NotificationTypeAdapter(val language: String) : TypeAdapter<TransModel>() {
    override fun write(out: JsonWriter?, value: TransModel?) {
        if (out == null || value == null) return
        out.beginObject()
        out.name("title")
        out.value(value.getValueByLanguage(language))
        out.endObject()
    }

    override fun read(reader: JsonReader?): TransModel? {
        if (reader == null) return null
        val jsonParser = JsonParser()
        val je = jsonParser.parse(reader)
        val trans = TransModel(language, (je.asString))
        return trans
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't found proper answer I am using new retrofit client for every call.

```
return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(okHttpClient.build())
                .build()
```

If anyone have more proper answer, Please suggest me some.

Comment: you might could use some interceptor that can change your params at run time, with which you could go through proper solution. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489261/retrofit-interceptor-on-different-module-in-feature-based-clean-architecture-and

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Retrofit method [newBuilder](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Retrofit.html#newBuilder) to get a new builder and there set a different `OkHttpClient` with different attributes. Put something like this into your `else` case:

```
retrofit.newBuilder()
        .client(anotherOkHttpClientWithOtherAttributes.build())
        .build()
```

Comment: Is it uses same retrofit instance for all retrofit client?

Comment: 'language' remains same

Comment: yes it stays the same because if you just copy and paste the answer you don't change the GsonConverterFactory. If you use the `newBuilder` method all attributes are copied and you have to adjust the new ones, therefore you have to add `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))` to your new builder in order to change it.

Comment: Sorry, but I know how to copy something, please make clear first and then comment. Please check my edit part for my coping skill..

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't my intention to doubt your copying skills. For my point of view the only thing that prevents now the language from changing is that the function is called with the same language, or no language at all so the default language is used. Check in the debugger what language is set.

Comment: I have checked It. First time retrofit client creation it is "en", after changing app language, I am passing "gu", but It is not changing, it remains same, "en"

Comment: At this point I can only guess, it's either an issue in your `TransModel` or `NotificationTypeAdapter`.

Comment: Can you please help me out for correct flow!!.. Check my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can add Credentials manual as Header To your request.

Example:

```
@GET("user")
Call<UserDetails> getUserDetails(@Header("Authorization") String credentials)

Credentials.basic("ausername","apassword");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change **BASE_URL** at runtime by passing it as a parameter with the use of **`@Url`** annotation.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST()
fun testService(@Url baseUrl: String,
                @Field("exampleParam") exampleParam: String): Observable<String>
```

Please try this and let me know for any query.

Comment: it says "@Url cannot be used with @POST URL (parameter #1)"